# Parse HTML modified by Javascript

Tags: ruby, parsing, html-parsing, capybara, mechanize

I want to submit a form in WebPage, when i submit my form the web add using Javascript a new fields. I would like to parse this new fields.
I was using Mechanize but it is not interpret javascript, I have tested capybara but I want to do this in background

Are there any alternative?

Comment: What have you written? We can write solutions all day long, but they won't help you much since you'd have to restructure your code to fit it. Supply a snippet showing your effort that we can correct/build-upon.

Comment: The javascript adds some form fields? That doesn't sound hard to reproduce in ruby.

Comment: @theTinMan I cannot write anything, I still do not know that gem will be used.

Comment: @pguardiario Yes, javascript add form fields dynamic, and I would like to parse this using Ruby

Answer (score 0):

You can do that much easier without evaluating Javascript using Capybara's autowaiting that is enabled in all Capybara's methods. Methods like:

```
find(locator)
```

will wait automatically up to 2 seconds. You can change limit by specifiing another value to default_wait_time, e.g.:

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = 5
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, it works but my ruby code must run in a enviroment where GUI is not possible, therefore I cannot use Capybara. Any idea? Is it possible run in background?

Comment: You can use headless driver. But why do you think that using webdriver isn't possible in your env?

Comment: I am running my app in CentOS and I cannot install firefox or chrome, because is a server without GUI

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try [Poltergeist](http://rubygems.org/gems/poltergeist). It's some sort of headless driver for Capybara.